# Given $G:=S_7,M:=\{1,...,7\},g:=(1\, 3\, 6)\cdot(3\, 5),x := 5,$ calculate $g\cdot x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Given
>
> $$\begin{align}
> G& := S_7, \\
> M& := \{1,...,7\},\\
>  g &:= (1 \, 3 \, 6) \cdot (3 \, 5), \\
> x &:= 5, 
> \end{align}$$
>
> calculate $g \cdot x$.

I would simply do:

$$
((1 \, 3 \, 6) \cdot (3 \, 5))\cdot(5) = (3 \, 5 \, 6 \, 1) \cdot (5) = (3 \, 5 \, 6 \, 1)
$$

But the solution is:

$$
((1 \, 3 \, 6) \cdot (3 \, 5))\cdot(5) = ((1 \, 3 \, 6)) \cdot (3) = 6
$$

How is it so?

Comment: The $5$ here is not a permutation, it's what the permutation acts on. Note that there are no parentheses around the $5$ in the problem statement!

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer for you if you were to adopt the notation that you write the permutations themselves with the parentheses but if you wish to talk about how a permutation acts on a specific element you write that element in square brackets instead to make it clear that the element being acted upon is not to be confused as another permutation or cycle... writing it as $((1~3~6)(3~5))[5] = (1~3~6)[(3~5)[5]]=(1~3~6)[3]=6$

Comment: Ok, the usage of the parentheses in the solution had left me confused... Everything clear. How can I close this post?

Comment: @zest16 you can leave it open for someone else if they need it :)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: FWIW I give the text that give the question a few wet noodle lashes for not being clear and unnecessarily ambiguous in notation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ is a bijection on the underlying set $\overline{1, n}=\{1, \dots, n\}$. Thus $\sigma\cdot m$ for $m\in\overline{1, n}$ is $\sigma$ *evaluated as a bijection at $m$*.

> If $\sigma=(1 \, 3 \, 6)$ and $\tau=(3 \, 5)$, then $(\sigma\circ\tau)(5)=\sigma(\tau(5))=\sigma(3)$, since $\tau: 5\mapsto 3$, so that $(\sigma\circ\tau)(5)=\sigma(3)=6$ because $\sigma: 3\mapsto 6$; put in a diagram: $$5\stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto} 3\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto} 6.$$